# What is the right definition of "cheeky"?

Tags: meaning

Whenever anyone from US hears me say "cheeky" to (or about) my kids, they always ask what it means. When I try to explain, they suggest "mischievous", but apparently it has more negative connotation than the "cheeky" I mean (the best I can explain it is mischievous, but cute about it). When I mean it negatively I use "naughty", not "cheeky".
So, is there a better definition, or am I using it wrong?

Comment: peppa pig, a nick jr tv show say cheeky like all the time

Comment: 'Cheeky' is quite (and often unhelpfully) polysemous. [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cheeky) has: impudent or irreverent, typically in an amusing way.
"a cheeky grin" ...
synonyms: impudent, impertinent, insolent, ... mannerless, rude, insulting.

Answer (score 11):

Your usage of *cheeky* is perfectly correct. The NOAD definition aptly captures your intended meaning:

> [**cheeky**](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1232358#m_en_us1232358)
>   impudent or irreverent, typically in an endearing or amusing way

Unfortunately, this word is not too common among American speakers. It may be that a cultural difference accounts for the fact (my conjecture) that American speakers are more likely to use adjectives (or adjectival phrases) that are more specific than *cheeky* to describe their children's behavior. For instance, you might hear:

> - *Little Johnny's such a piece of work.*
> - *Amy's quite a character.*
> - *Our five-year-old's got some real spunk.*
> - *What a zesty little chipmunk!*
> - *Jimmy always seems to have a will of his own.*

As for a better alternative to *cheeky*, I do not think there is one, except you want to go for either of the following:

- [*Impudent*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1257411#m_en_us1257411) — a more formal synonym that would rarely be used in casual conversation.
- [*Sassy*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1287307#m_en_us1287307) — a more informal synonym, but I doubt that parents would use this to describe their kids; it is more common among friends, and for some reasons, more feminine than masculine.

Finally, I would say that *mischievous* does not always have a negative connotation. It has two degrees of meaning, one which is much more negative than the other. I quote the relevant NOAD definition:

> **[mischievous](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1268316#m_en_us1268316)**
>   (of a person, animal, or their behavior) causing or showing a fondness for causing trouble in a playful way

It clearly isn't a direct synonym of *cheeky*, but it could work very well for related behavioral descriptions. And I daresay *mischievous* is way more popular than *cheeky* in conversations among American parents.

Comment: @Jimi Oke I don't agree with you that _cheeky bastard_ has a uniformly positive connotation, even amongst Brits who are familiar with it.  For example, check out this scene from the movie _Snatch_, where Gorgeous George, a boxer, decks out Mikey the piker for calling him "a fat fuck", while replying "cheeky bastard!": _[Mikey vs. Gorgeous George](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nG_Nwp0wZc0&t=0m29s)_ (Youtube link, starts immediately)  I have definitely heard the phrase used in other situations where the speaker felt that his antagonist was giving him too much "lip."

Comment: @Billare: I never said anything about *cheeky bastard* being a positive description. Heck, the word *bastard* is not even in my dictionary! *Fat fuck* and *cheeky bastard* could be considered obscene, derogatory or loaded insults by some. However, those may be phrases that *tough* friends may throw at each other without batting eyelids. My answer here was strictly given in the context of parents' description of their children's behaviors. Some parents may be comfortable describing their child as a *mischievous little punk* or *cheeky brat*; but some may not. I think the tone says a lot, too.

Comment: @Jimi Oke D'oh! I don't know why I put the _bastard_ in italics; sometimes (oftentimes, really) I write faster than I think.  But I think the fact that George put the appellation on an epithet shows that _cheeky_'s use isn't uniformly positive; he was responding to what he thought was Mikey's audacious responses in what seemed to be a clearly inferior position.   If I've veered too oblique in comment, apologies, so let me be clearer: _Cheeky_ has clear usage amongst Brits when they feel their interlocutor is giving them too much sass.  I would be pretty circumspect in using it.

Comment: @Billare: Haha, OK. I do agree that *cheeky*'s use isn't *uniformly positive*, as you say. In the UK and other parts of the Commonwealth, it's fine to use it for kids, though, as it could be an endearing term. I think it's similar to words like *naughty*, which used to be harmless but now has several shades of meaning I wouldn't want to go into. Like I said, *cheeky*'s scarce in the US (in relation to kids), for some reason.

Comment: @Jimi Oke I feel like _cheeky_ is one of those words perfect for someone to deliver backhanded insults with, to say something like, "Your kid's a little a devil, isn't it he?" or "He's a bit of imp, that one."

Comment: @Billare: Ah, *little devil* — forgot that one! Definitely could be a backhanded insult. For me, it would certainly be rude to describe someone else's child (especially to their face) as cheeky, but it's OK if it's the parent using the word to describe theirs.

Comment: @Jimi Oke: Somehow I always thought that impudent was much more negative, someone really rude.

Comment: @Elendill: Yeah, it does seem that *impudent* would be taken to mean *outright rude*. *Cheeky*, on the other hand, mostly has a playful connotation...it all depends on the tone and context

Comment: As an Australian English speaker, and a parent of a child who I regularly refer to as _cheeky_, I absolutely agree with your answer, Jimi. I think it's important to note the difference between _cheeky_ and _cheek_ though. _Giving cheek_ is definitely negative, where _being cheeky_ (especially in relation to children) is not.

Comment: @Loquacity: Great point, and thanks for the input.

Comment: @Loquacity http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cheeky:   

"_Cheeky_ is a word used by English people like myself. 1. it is a word used to describe someone who does something or says something sort of disrespectful and sometimes rude, but says it in a cunning way. 2. can also be used in a more serious way i.e. if you found out that one of your friends has been talking behind your back, you might say that she is a 'cheeky bitch'"

Comment: Hi Billare. Well, I don't put a lot of faith in Urban Dictionary at the best of times, but I would hesitate to give it such a negative connotation as all that. I much prefer the NOAD definition given by Jimi above, which puts the emphasis on "endearing or amusing" rather than cunning.

Answer (score 1):

We use the term *cheeky* here in Southeastern North Carolina to mean mischievous in  a cute way.  To give too much lip is to be cheeky.

Comment: There are no full stops, spaces, Right Capitalization, or correct grammar used in North Carolina?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *impish* might work?

Defined as "showing a lack of respect for somebody/something in a way that is amusing rather than serious" in the Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary or...

"having or showing a playful desire to cause trouble : playful and mischievous" in Meriam-Webster.

Comment: 'Impish' and even 'mischievous' can have a fairly strong negative emphasis, but it's still a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Another Aussie here — I use *cheeky* quite a lot in the following example situations.

- I walk into the bathroom when my girlfriend is having a shower and she flicks water over me. I respond "oh you cheeky brat".
- A friend pinches my seat at the pub and I respond "you cheeky bugger".

In both those the *cheeky* has an upward tone and the word following is fairly flat.

Obviously in both situations the person is doing something only slightly naughty or mischevious.

I also think it could be used the same as "are you giving me lip?" in other situations where back chatting is what's occurring. I introduced the word to a friend in France who now delights in calling his 10-year old daughter a cheeky monkey, and she is the definition of it!