# What do you call a guest who treats your home as theirs?

Tags: single-word-requests

When a guest shows up at the door and you invite them inside, typically they will hesitate and decline at first.

However, I know one ‘guest’ that readily accepts, walks in, and sits down on a couch of their choosing.

When you ask your guest if they would like something to eat or drink, typically they will either say they are fine or request something simple like water.

Instead this person asks if there's any milk.

- Is there a word for a guest who behaves unconventionally? A person who shows a lack of restraint, or treats someone else's house like their own?

Comment: "Genuine" comes to mind, as do "literalist" (because when you ask a question that you don't expect to be taken at face value, this person does take it at face value) and "unfeigning" (because the person doesn't pretend that his or her desires are other than they truly are, for form's sake).

Comment: It's someone who "makes himself at home".  "Make yourself at home" is a common expression meaning to treat the home (or, figuratively speaking, some other accommodation) as if it were your own.

Comment: (But this individual probably has a lack of social restraints that has some sesquipedalian name.)

Comment: In my experience, this kind of person is called an "American".

Comment: @ralph.m I'm American and I agree. If you don't want me to drink your milk, don't offer me anything to drink! Similarly, if you don't want me to come in and invite me anyway, you should never contact me again because you're not a person worth associating with. If the offer is fake it's worse than not offering.

Comment: Parasite, scrounger(informal), freeloader (slang), sponger (UK informal), sponge (US informal), bum (informal), bludger (Austral. & N.Z. informal), sorner (Scot.)

Comment: @ralph.m I wonder what situations we could use to describe Autralians?

Comment: A friend?  Anyway why would a guest come to your door but be reluctant to come in?

Comment: @neil There are plenty of situations, for example, a neighbor who stopped by to deliver a package delivered to the wrong address.

Comment: @seafood258 Ok, I understand your reason for the quotes round "guest" now. I don't think I've got any better answer than the ones given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Uninhibited](http://i.word.com/idictionary/uninhibited)

> able to express thoughts and feelings freely : not inhibited

*Unreserved* will also fit quite well.

However, take into account that the level of restraint expected from a guest is strongly dependent on culture. What may *you* perceive as an uninhibited behaviour, *someone from a different culture* may perceive as a completely normal one. E.g. if I am invited and my host expects me to reject what he is offering me, I may be quite reluctant to accept his invitation the next time.

So be careful in assigning these words to someone's behaviour too easily.

Answer (score 1):

Cheeky

"impudent or irreverent, typically in an endearing or amusing way"

[What is the right definition of "cheeky"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22303/what-is-the-right-definition-of-cheeky)